# Android Ad above keyboard

Tags: android, view

I have an android application which has several view and a admob view at the very bottom:

```
Textview
Button
Textview
Admob view
```

When I open the keyboard, everything resizes because of

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

This does not look nice, so I can disable it via

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

When I open the keyboard now, I can't see the ad anymore because it is behind the keyboard ;(

Is it possible to fix all views, but when I open the keyboard, the admob view shall be above the keyboard ?!

Answer (score 0):

This will make it possible to scroll through everything but the ad, which will always be visible at the bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ad" >

        <EverythingButAd />

    </ScrollView>

    <Ad 
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Remember:

- Set `android:layout_width` & `android:layout_height`; I left them out in the example to improve readability
- Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`